# Hard Drive Utilization over time on Windows 10?

Tags: hard-drive

I've noticed the hard drive use light flashing like crazy and I'm not using this PC (hardly ever do). How can I log what's going on for a time period?

For example: what files are being created/accessed/deleted/moved/copied etc, what folders or programs are being used/accessed. If an external device/site is doing the access (I do have a Cloud/NAS), note that, perhaps a MAC ID, IP address, etc. I've seen a number of software apps to take a snapshot of disk usage, but I want to see what's going on without my (seeming) intervention.

Comment: It’s most likely defragmentation and whatnot. Windows runs a lot of maintenance tasks when it’s idle and not on battery.

Answer (score 0):

#### How do I find out what files are being created/accessed/deleted/moved/copied etc

You can use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645)

It monitors file system, registry, process and thread activity in real time and can write the events to a log file for later analysis.

> **Introduction**
>
> Process Monitor is an advanced monitoring tool for Windows that shows
> real-time file system, Registry and process/thread activity. It
> combines the features of two legacy Sysinternals utilities, Filemon
> and Regmon, and adds an extensive list of enhancements including rich
> and non-destructive filtering, comprehensive event properties such
> session IDs and user names, reliable process information, full thread
> stacks with integrated symbol support for each operation, simultaneous
> logging to a file, and much more. Its uniquely powerful features will
> make Process Monitor a core utility in your system troubleshooting and
> malware hunting toolkit.
>
> **Overview of Process Monitor Capabilities**
>
> Process Monitor includes powerful monitoring and filtering
> capabilities, including:
>
> - More data captured for operation input and output parameters
> - Non-destructive filters allow you to set filters without losing data
> - Capture of thread stacks for each operation make it possible in many cases to identify the root cause of an operation
> - Reliable capture of process details, including image path, command line, user and session ID
> - Configurable and moveable columns for any event property
> - Filters can be set for any data field, including fields not configured as columns
> - Advanced logging architecture scales to tens of millions of captured events and gigabytes of log data
> - Process tree tool shows relationship of all processes referenced in a trace
> - Native log format preserves all data for loading in a different Process Monitor instance
> - Process tooltip for easy viewing of process image information
> - Detail tooltip allows convenient access to formatted data that doesn't fit in the column
> - Cancellable search
> - Boot time logging of all operations

Download link http://download.sysinternals.com/files/ProcessMonitor.zip

Source Windows Sysinternals [Process Monitor v3.32](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645)